# In swift how do you define a type to a protocol with an internal type

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift2

I made the following protocol. It defines an object that can infinitely scale between `start` and `end` given a value `0-1`.

```
protocol Scalable {
    typealias ScalableType

    var start:ScalableType { get }
    var end:ScalableType { get }
    func scale(dub:Double) -> ScalableType?
    func series(count count:Int) -> [ScalableType?]
}
```

An example implemenation:

```
struct DoubleRange:Scalable {
    typealias ScalableType = Double
    let start:Double
    let end:Double

    var diff:Double {
        return end - start
    }

    func scale(dub: Double) -> Double? {
        return start + (dub * diff)
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is figure out a way to have a variable defined as a property which allows for any `Scalable` where `ScalableType` is `UIColor`.

This works:

```
func foo<T where T:Scalable, T.ScalableType == UIColor>(scaler:T) {}
```

But i can't figure out an equivalent way to define a property as such. Was thinking of somehow making a wrapper, but still can't figure it out.

Ideally I'd like something that this expresses (even though is obviously not compiling code)

```
var foo:Scalable<where Self.ScalableType == UIColor>?
```

Comment: Does the `Scalable` property's `ScalableType` need to be a `UIColor` or is it any `Scalable` with the `ScalableType` defined as `UIColor` will have this new property?

Comment: @keithbhunter For just this once specific instance i want a property who's object Conforms to `Scalable` and the internal type is `UIColor`. There will be other implementations of `Scalable` with different inernal types.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the generic on the class/struct definition:

```
struct ObjectWithScalableColor<T: Scalable where T.ScalableType == UIColor> {
    let scalableColor: T
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately then i'd have to do `var foo: ObjectWithScalableColor<ColorImplementation>` and at that point i may as well just do `var foo:ColorImplementaiton`